# How can I recover a vdi (VirtualBox) file?

Tags: virtualbox, data-recovery

I just deleted my VirtualBox.dvi file and lost valuable information.

I'm using Ubuntu 9.04 and the VirtualBox is a Windows XP image.

Detail 1: I deleted using gnome, not terminal.

Detail 2: The file isn't in trash, because when I saw that I was removing the file, I have canceled operation. So the file isn't in original folder neither in trash folder.

I want to use foremost or scalpel, but I don't know how to use these programs with dvi files...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've found the dvi header:

3C 3C 3C 20 53 75 6E 20

\x3C\x3C\x3C\x20\x53\x75\x6E\x20

And footer is dynamic...

Comment: Can you tell us if you were able to recover your data or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dvi file was located on the same partition as Ubuntu (or is in use by you) there is a small chance for recovery. *Foremost* and *scalpel* both read directly from the disk or partition, and need to be instructed to work with the correct header and file end. As VDI's are often some gigabytes in size, it's not getting easier.

If you want to take the *foremost* approach, I would suggest looking for the header format using your favorite search engine. In any case, if your vdi was located on the disk you are currently using, power the machine off and use a LiveCD so your disk does not get touched.